# Will usermod update all file and folder permissions correctly?

Tags: permissions, docker, chmod, chown

I have an issue with docker, because docker will write files with UID 1000, but my UID in the host is 1001.

a workaround is changing UID of my host user to 1000
that means

change the existing user in my host system with UID 1000 to 1002

change my desired user in my host system with 1001 to 1000

question: will usermod actually update all file and folder permissions correctly?

Comment: or... add 1000 and 1001 to the same group,

Comment: that would still create all files with the wrong owner though, but good point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the manpage of `usermod`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/usermod.8):

```
-u, --uid UID
   The new numerical value of the user's ID. [...]

   The user's mailbox, and any files which the user owns and which are located in the
   user's home directory will have the file user ID changed automatically.

   The ownership of files outside of the user's home directory must be fixed manually.

   The change of the user ownership of files inside of the user's home directory is also
   not done if the home dir owner uid is different from the current or new user id. This
   is a safety measure for special home directories such as /.
```

It can fix ownership of some files as mentioned, but it doesn't fix *permissions* of anything, though.